# Como abrir arquivo com window.open em um post?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, arquivo, post

Meu controller retorna dois tipos de arquivos: pdf e excel.

```
return File(stream, "application/pdf");

return File(new MemoryStream(ep.GetAsByteArray()), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", $"Relatorio.xlsx");
```

Quando a requisição pode ser feita por get, faço da seguinte maneira:

```
window.open(urlComParametros, "_blank");
```

Dessa forma é aberta uma nova aba, se o tipo do arquivo for pdf ele abre para visualização, e se o tipo for excel o arquivo é baixado.

Porém, agora preciso fazer a requisição por post. Já consegui, convertendo o arquivo para byte[] e depois convertendo para Base64String. Então, no success da minha requisição faço os seguinte para abrir os arquivos:

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + data, "_blank");
window.open("data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64," + data, "_blank");
```

Dessa forma funciona, porém existem alguns problemas:

- Não consegui alterar o title da aba
- Não consegui alterar o nome do arquivo excel que é baixado
- Não funciona no IE

Como posso solucionar esses problemas? Ou existe alguma maneira melhor de retornar esses arquivos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o caso do título da aba, você pode usar JavaScript. Um exemplo usando jQuery:

```
var wnd = window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + data, "_blank");
$(wnd.document).find('html').append('<head><title>Um título</title></head>');
```

No caso do Excel, o nome do arquivo deve ser definido em *Controller*. Para o seu caso, [use esta forma de `File()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File(System.Byte[],System.String,System.String)), mas, como você definiu um `window.open`, a dificuldade aumenta um pouco mais.

Sendo assim, podemos usar a ideia de um link invisível, que não deixa de ser um ~artifício técnico~, ao invés do `window.open`:

```
var uri = 'data:application/pdf;base64," + data;

var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.href = uri;
downloadLink.download = "meuarquivo.pdf";

document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
```

Já no caso do IE, você pode usar este outro ~artifício técnico~ (note que é CSV, não XSL ou XSLX):

```
var IEwindow = window.open();
IEwindow.document.write('sep=,\r\n' + CSV);
IEwindow.document.close();
IEwindow.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, nomeArquivo + ".csv");
IEwindow.close();
```

Comment: Cara, o append não funcionou pq o pdf é aberto naquela tela de visualização de pdf padrão do chrome e aparentemente ele substitui o título para "data:". No caso do excel, aonde eu devo definir o nome do arquivo? Pois eu converto um FileStream em byte[] e depois em uma string base64, mas em nenhum desse lugares dá pra alterar o nome. Desde já, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @AndréMoraisMartins Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Show! Valeu cara!